# Edmunds dealership API

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am trying to play around with the Edmunds API data but when I use the example code, the JSON isn't showing up (it is just a blank page). I am fairly new to API's and just want the JSON to show up so I can start disecting it. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Edmunds API Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results-body"></div>
    <script>
        window.sdkAsyncInit = function() {
            // Instantiate the SDK
            var res = new EDMUNDSAPI('YOUR API KEY');
            // Optional parameters
            var options = {
                "zipcode": "90019"
            };
            // Callback function to be called when the API response is returned
            function success(res) {
                var body = document.getElementById('results-body');
                body.innerHTML = "This repairshop's name is : " + res.repairshops[0].name;
            }
            // Oops, Houston we have a problem!
            function fail(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
            // Fire the API call
            res.api('/api/dealer/v2/repairshops', options, success, fail);
            // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
        };
        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, sdkjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "path/to/sdk/file";
            sdkjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, sdkjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'edmunds-jssdk'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For all those wondering, I did put in my API key.

Answer (score 0):

The api endpoint you use must end with `/` (*you are missing that slash*)

```
res.api('/api/dealer/v2/repairshops/', options, success, fail);
```

---

Their documentation shows your code, but their API console shows the real endpoints (http://edmunds.mashery.com/io-docs)